# How to create multi select paypal smart button

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to create payment page with PayPal smart button.

My product has 3 plans. I can put 3 PayPal buttons on my site. but It's not match with my design.

I'd like to combine 3 plans to 1 button. Is it possible? And how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the smart button you could have some Javascript code that pulls in the value of what the user has selected, using `document.getElementById('...').value` or similar